# External HDD's Label not visible on some Computers?

Tags: windows-8, portable-harddrive

1. I recently used a windows 7 32bit computer to format my external hard-disk
2. I applied a label for it
3. However the drive label is not visible on other computers
4. The device get mounted correctly on windows 8 and i can even access the files without a problem
5. This has happened to me before and when i reformat the device in a newer operating system and apply the label it becomes visible on all computers
6. The problem is i don't have enough space on my local hard disks to backup my external drive so it cannot be formatted !
7. Renaming the label wont work

i just want all computers to be able to show the label for the drive

Drive details:usb 3.0,1TB, ADATA HV610

Comment: If the drive label's not visible, what do you see exactly? Can you try changing the label using the `label` command from an *elevated* command prompt, then checking on another PC?

Comment: it just say "Local Disk" in windows 8
i tried label command the label is correctly shown by the label command and i also changed it again using label command however its still not changed in windows explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution

the reason was a folder named "Autorun.inf" inside the harddisk
when that folder and its content are deleted the problem went away

unfortunately that folder is the only solution i know to prevent viruses from creating an "Autorun.inf" file