# How to prevent viruses from creating Autorun.inf in storage devices?

Tags: windows, virus, autorun

One of the solutions that I've come up with is to create a new folder named `Autorun.inf` inside the storage device and placing some dummy files inside it. So, whenever a virus tries the win32 api to delete `autorun.inf` as a file it will fail.

However this scenario causes a problem -
[External HDD's Label not visible on some Computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/571213/external-hdds-label-not-visible-on-some-computers)

Is there any other way to ensure that an `autorun.inf` file is never created by viruses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that my own solution. **creating a folder named Autorun.inf** is the best solution.

---

I already have an antivirus installed But the Storage devices are built to be used to share data with multiple computers.

sometimes you have no choice but to plug the device into a computer with no antivirus(possibly even infected).

So such a trick is compulsory ! As an additional example : you cannot install antiviruses to public labs of a university(some don't have an AV) , internet cafe. The aforementioned trick does work for most of the viruses which create an autorun.inf, however its not an alternative to an AV but rather an addition.

---

**Works because most native compilable file apis (such as windows api) treat folders and files differently.**

Answer (score 3):

I would run proper anti-virus/anti-malware software to ensure that you do not get viruses in the first place.

There is probably no use at all in trying to trick one particular piece of malware into thinking that it has infected a storage device. You will not be able to trick every bit of malware into thinking that it has already infected your device.

Prevention, rather than cure.